# how to differentiate between javascript submit and manually clicking submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, click, submit

how to differentiate between javascript triggered submit and manually clicking form submit
sample code below

```
 function myfunction()
 {
    document.getElementById("id_searchform").submit();
    return true;
 }
```

form:

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-4'>
      <div class='clszipcode' ><span>Enter Zipcode</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class='col-md-4'>
      <div class='clstxtzipcode' ><input type="text" name="zip_code" id="txtZipcode"></div>
   </div>
   <div class='col-md-4'>
      <div class='clsbtnzip' ><input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Search" class="button_example"  ></div>
   </div>
</div>
<a href="#"  onclick="return myfunction();" >click to submit</a>
```

Comment: You know when my function is invoked it is javascript triggered submit.

Comment: take a hidden input and supply a different value with javascript submit. ie `<input type="hidden" value="manual" name="submittype">` in javascript set `...submittype.value = 'js'`

Comment: if i attach a onclick event to <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Search" class="button_example" onclick="validate()"  > it will call myfunction()  and validate()

Comment: and what does validate() do? only clicking the "real" submit button won't trigger myfunction() then...

Comment: but myfunction() triggers validate() and validate function may set some variable like real submit var realsubmit="yes"

Comment: any way using type="hidden" i could differentiate it ,thanks for ur answers

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand:

1. You want to detect whether the user clicked the link to submit the form.
2. You want to detect if the user clicked the submit button to submit the form.
3. You have another function called `validate()` which will use this information in some way.

If this is the case, consider using a variable to store whether the link was clicked before triggering the form to submit.

1. Initialize global variable `wasClicked` to `false`
2. When link is clicked set `wasClicked` to `true`
3. Trigger form submit after `wasClicked` is set.
4. Run `validate()` when form is submitted
5. Check `if(wasClicked){...}` in `validate()`

Here is a [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/miketiheju/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: And by the way, when JS is not enabled in browser, the onsubmit event won't trigger. Then the form is not polluted with an hidden input for this case.