# How to differentiate between JavaScript submit and manual submit (for forms I don't own)

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

My question is almost the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321252/how-to-differentiate-between-javascript-submit-and-manually-clicking-submit).  But I have to ask the question again because I can not accept the answer that the OP there has seem to accept.  I like a solution to work on any form on any page, so adding a hidden field won't work.

I have examined the submit events from one that's programmatically created and one that's created manually (actual click, return, etc).  And as far as I can tell, the submit events are the same.  Is there some ways to tell the difference?

Say on http://www.bing.com, using Chrome console:

```
var loginForm = document.forms[0];
var submitEvent = new Event('submit');
loginForm.dispatchEvent(submitEvent);
```

Note: I only need this to work on Chrome and JavaScript only.

Comment: The solution would work on any form, it doesn't seem to mention hidden fields at all. Also the OP didn't accept the answer.

Comment: If it is for forms you don't own then why do you need to do anything on submit?

Comment: Please look at OP's comment there: any way using type="hidden" i could differentiate it ,thanks for ur answers –  srinidhi

Comment: You can also look at this documentation of looking at the event source: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: @HenryChang Comments are not answers, did you try the answer to the question?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, right, thanks.  So, from my understanding of the answer, it relies on detecting click as well, i.e. programmatic click vs real click.  Let me give that a shot.